# How to run a docker image on Digital Ocean droplet?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean

I have a Ubuntu based droplet on Digital Ocean with Docker installed, and where I uploaded my docker image.tar file from my desktop. I uploaded this image.tar file into /home/newuser/app directory. Next, I loaded the image.tar using following command:

```
sudo docker load -i image.tar
```

The image has been loaded. I checked.

When I run these following lines, I can't see my image app on public IP connected to my droplet instance:

```
sudo docker run image
```

or

```
sudo docker run -p 80:80 image
```

How do you guys go about this?

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM r-base:3.5.0

# Install Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev/unstable \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev 


# Add shiny user
RUN groupadd  shiny \
&& useradd --gid shiny --shell /bin/bash --create-home shiny



# Download and install ShinyServer
RUN wget --no-verbose https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-14.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb && \
    gdebi shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb


# Install R packages that are required
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('Benchmarking', 'plotly', 'DT'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"

# Copy configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY /app /srv/shiny-server/

# Make the ShinyApp available at port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Copy further configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

The code for shiny-server.conf :

```
# Define the user we should use when spawning R Shiny processes
run_as shiny;

# Define a top-level server which will listen on a port
server {
  # Instruct this server to listen on port 80. The app at dokku-alt need expose PORT 80, or 500 e etc. See the docs
  listen 80;

  # Define the location available at the base URL
  location / {

    # Run this location in 'site_dir' mode, which hosts the entire directory
    # tree at '/srv/shiny-server'
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Define where we should put the log files for this location
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # Should we list the contents of a (non-Shiny-App) directory when the user 
    # visits the corresponding URL?
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

And code for shiny-server.sh :

```
# Make sure the directory for individual app logs exists
mkdir -p /var/log/shiny-server
chown shiny.shiny /var/log/shiny-server

exec shiny-server >> /var/log/shiny-server.log 2>&1
```

Comment: sudo docker run -p 80:80 image should do it if port 80 is internally exposed in the container.  Unless you have a firewall running in the droplet.

Comment: how do you check if port 80 is exposed in the container? if this is something related to Dockerfile, then yeah port 80 is explicitly declared in that document. I have similar issue when I run the image from local docker on my desktop, meaning the image won't load on localhost.

Comment: Post your docker file for starters

Comment: I have added the dockerfile to my question. see if there are any anomalies specifically related to image loading on host. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need to EXPOSE port 80 in the docker file when you run the container with -p 80:80, except maybe as a hint to others: https://forums.docker.com/t/what-is-the-use-of-expose-in-docker-file/37726/2

You should probably post your shiny-server.conf, but I betcha that you either specified no port (in which case shiny-server starts on port 3838) or a port other than 80. Make sure you modify this line in the config file:

```
listen 3838
```

Comment: I have included the code for shiny-server.conf and shiny-server.sh; there is a code line for `listen 80`, do you think anything is missing? It is really weird that my app would show when run through R-studio;  but won't show on localhost when run as image through docker.

Comment: Truly weird.  There's only one more thing I have.  Try exposing a different port than 80 in shiny.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your help. I did try a couple things but I still won't see my app on either http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1/   -  I built my docker image from start and I get this message at the end (if this says anything regarding the potential solution): SECURITY WARNING: You are building a docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-r-wxr-xr-x' permissions.